# The method must override a superClass method for ModelResolver interface

Tags: java, maven, interface, overriding

I am trying to create a class that implements the 'ModelResolver' interface 
See http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-model-builder/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/resolution/ModelResolver.html

Here is the class

```
 class MyResolver implements ModelResolver {

    private final File artifactFile;

    public MyResolver(File artifactFile) {
        this.artifactFile = artifactFile;
    }

    @Override
    public void addRepository(Repository arg0)
            throws InvalidRepositoryException {
        /** Nothing to do here as aether will take care of this. */
    }

    @Override
    public void addRepository(Repository arg0, boolean arg1)
            throws InvalidRepositoryException {
        /** Nothing to do here as aether will take care of this. */
    }

    @Override
    public ModelResolver newCopy() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public ModelSource resolveModel(Parent parent)
            throws UnresolvableModelException {
        Artifact artifact;
        try {
            /** Use parent class getRemoteArtifact method */
            artifact = getRemoteArtifact(parent.getGroupId(),
                    parent.getArtifactId(),
                    parent.getVersion(),
                    "pom");
        } catch (ArtifactResolutionException e) {
            throw new UnresolvableModelException(e.getMessage(),
                    parent.getGroupId(),
                    parent.getArtifactId(),
                    parent.getVersion());
        }
        return new FileModelSource(artifact.getFile());
    }

    @Override
    public ModelSource resolveModel(String groupId,
                                    String artifactId,
                                    String version)
            throws UnresolvableModelException {
        return new FileModelSource(artifactFile);
    }
}
```

This gives me the following error

```
The method addRepository must override the super class method.
```

I am on java 1.7 and using eclipse for my development. What am I missing?
I also verifies that the compiler compliance level is set to 1.7 in eclipse

Comment: Did you correctly import `org.apache.maven.model.Repository`? Also, make sure you override `newCopy` and `resolveModel`.

Comment: Hi Yes I've verified the import and also am overriding the above two methods, still get the same error

Comment: Try to clean > build the project. (it's Eclipse)

Comment: post a full code of your class

Comment: anyway in this code class name and constructor name is different. it might be a mistake you did when you add this code to your question

Comment: oops, copy paste error, I've edited

Comment: Added teh entire class, clean build does not fix it